# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Estaba haciendo un tutorial de crud con php y mysqul y me salio ese error

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['save_task'] )){
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];

   $query = "INSERT INTO task(title, description) VALUES($title, $description)";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

?>

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'title , Test desc)' at line
> 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Crud-PHP\save_task.php:9 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Crud-PHP\save_task.php(9):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO tas...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Crud-PHP\save_task.php on line 9

no se como solucionarlo y me gustaria que alguien me de una mano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te faltan las comillas ya que es un string

```
$query = "INSERT INTO task(title, description) VALUES('{$title}', '{$description}')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

aunque esto es propenso a sql injection por lo que seria mejor

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO task(title, description) VALUES(?, ?)");
// ss por que son 2 string
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ss', $title, $descripcion);

// validamos que se enviaron los campos
// esto es igual a un if else
// expresion_a_evaluar ? si_es_true : si_no_else;

$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 0;
$description = isset($_POST['description']) ?  $_POST['description'] : 0 ;

// validamos que no sea alguan 0
if ( !$title || !$description){
  // finalizamos la ejecucion
  die("uno o ambos parametro sin definir!");
}
// si ambos estan definidos
// continuamos con la ejecucion
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

referencia:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

Los valores que se intenta ingresar para las columnas: "title" y "description" de la tabla "task" con la query mostrada, se está tratando de insertar sin las comillas por ende la variable: "$query", tendría que ser:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO task(title, description) VALUES ('$title', '$description')";
```